# Clean redirect after successful login using loginPopup MSAL

Tags: azure, vue.js, azure-active-directory, vite, azure-ad-msal

I need some help with a project I'm working on. I've created a single-page application (SPA) in Vue using Vite, and I'm using the MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) LoginPopup to redirect the page after login.

In my app, I have an onBeforeMount hook that fetches the token and stores it. It runs once when you enter the web page.

The issue I'm facing is that when the LoginPopup and Vue Router method redirect the page to "localhost/something," the onBeforeMount hook has already been called, so it doesn't fetch the token again. This is because of the SPA nature of the application.

Many websites use a middle page that displays a message like "You will be redirected in 5, 4, 3..." and then moves you to the desired page.

I'm looking for a more elegant solution to recognize if the user is authenticated and retrieve the accessToken without fetching it every time, as it would be inefficient in terms of requests.

I've considered using Promises, but the MSAL package explicitly advises against it, stating:

"IMPORTANT: It is NOT recommended to have code that is dependent on the resolution of the Promise. This function will navigate away from the current browser window. It currently returns a Promise in order to reflect the asynchronous nature of the code running in this function."

In my homepage Vue file, I have the following code:

```
openLoginPopup() {

  this.msalI.loginPopup();
},
```

And in my app.vue file, the code is as follows:

```
onBeforeMount(async () => {
  await this.fetchAccessToken();
});
```

Is there an elegant way to handle the Azure B2C redirect and fetch the accessToken without fetching it every time? I've looked at the following resource on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-b2c-javascript-spa, but they are using Promises, which is not recommended in this case.

thank you!